# how to serve static content outside the db?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to figure out how to push static files, like an svg or an image, in a module without having to put it in the db. 
I've created a simple module that define a route with self.apos.app.get and  with pushAssets I send js and css to render a template, but how to serve an image or svg defined in the css? I can put them in prj_root/public but I'm unsure if this is the way to do it.
I've tried to put in my_module/public but they are not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put a file called `my.png` in `/public/images/my.png`, then it becomes accessible as `/images/my.png`. This is because Apostrophe sets up the `express.static` middleware for the `/public` folder.

If you put a file called `my.png` in `lib/modules/mymodule/public/my.png`, it becomes accessible as `/modules/mymodule/my.png`. This is because Apostrophe establishes symbolic links from each module's `/public` folder in `/public/modules`.

(When running on Windows, Apostrophe copies the files there at startup instead, and for a tiny performance boost we may eventually do that in production for Linux too, but either way the result is the same.)