# static files in nodejs apostrophe cms

Tags: node.js, file, static, content-management-system, apostrophe-cms

I am trying to deploy some static files in NodeJs Apostrophe CMS.
The css and js ones are ok, as desribed in the documentation.

however, in public folder I copy paste a png file - logo.png - and when I request http://localhost:3000/logo.png I have a 404.

Thanks

Comment: I copy a png file under `/public` in Apostrophe CMS and can successfully access it in browser.

Comment: ho my wrong, I was using apostrophe-assets/public.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you figured it out! For those with the same question, this has been answered a few times.

[Add static assets to Apostrophe project, specifically images and font files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44984368/add-static-assets-to-apostrophe-project-specifically-images-and-font-files)

[how to serve static content outside the db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42657414/how-to-serve-static-content-outside-the-db)